# Nc command works on it's own - but returning port range not valid in bash script

Tags: netcat

So I'm able to retrieve the firmware of a printer and saving it to a doc by typing:

```
echo '! U1 getvar "appl.name"' | nc -i2 10.67.12.144 5964>doc
```

However if I try to check a list of printers in a file (IP's) I get 'port range not valid'

```
for i in `cat $1`
do
echo -n "$i "
echo‘! U1 getvar "appl.name"’ | nc -i2 $1 5964>doc
done
```

I'm probably doing something silly here but i just cant figure out what the mistake could be?

Comment: Please post the contents of your file you are trying to read from + your script. Which shell are you using? BTW that `$1` argument to `nc` should probably be `$i`.

Comment: Hi Herman thank you for replying, inside the file I have a couple of test printer IP's
10.67.12.144
10.67.12.145
if the script is called X and the printer list is called Y, i run the script like so ./X Y
Ive pasted the full script above - my objective is to read from the Y file and echo the printer IPs with the firmware versions alongside them into a file called doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read each line from a file provided as first command-line argument with `read` in combination with a while-loop. Provided that the file contains an ip address on each line:

```
while read ip; do
    echo -n "$ip "
    echo '! U1 getvar "appl.name"' | nc -i2 $ip 5964 > doc
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Really nice way to approach it, thank you for your help Herman